# Plotly Ignoring "barmode=group" Argument in Bar Chart

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create a grouped barchart with this data on plotly, but that argument gets ignored each time and plotly creates a relative barchart instead. I tried changing the column, index, and value datatypes to no avail.

My code is below:

```
data='''
Brand   2018    2019    2020    2021
Hersheys    100 200 212 314
MilkyWay    105 106 214 178
Reeses  84  82  95  112
Payday  278 552 214 292
'''

brand = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
brand=pd.melt(brand,id_vars=['Brand'],value_vars=brand.columns)
brand=brand.rename(columns={'variable':'Year'})

agg_brand=brand[['value','Year']].groupby('Year').agg('sum').reset_index()
agg_brand.columns=['Year','value_sum']
brand=pd.merge(brand,agg_brand,on='Year',how='left')

brand['percent']=(brand['value']/brand['value_sum']*100).round(1).astype(str)+"%"
fig=px.bar(brand,x='Year',y='value',barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

I found this [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-express-bar-ignores-barmode-group/31511), but I have no clue how to apply it. I am lost (and I also have to make these charts by tomorrow) and any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image: Stacked Rather Than Grouped Barchart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `color` argument as well, and then you'll get the side-by-side bars.

```
fig=px.bar(brand,x='Year',y='value', barmode='group', color='Brand')
fig.show()
```

[image]

I tried this with your dataframe at various points in the creation and I might have done something wrong, but there's nothing to indicate that it *should need* `color` specified, even from reading the `plotly` code.